Помогите написать цикл для подсчёта по формуле на ассемблере для простой ЭВМ. Проблема в нехватке ячеек памяти
Необходимо реализовать циклический алгоритм:
Формула:

У модели есть 16 ячеек и 2 регистра.
Каждая команда
ассемблера состоит из мнемокода операции и операндов. Каждая строка может иметь
метку - идентификатор, состоящий не более чем из пяти символов, и отделяющийся от
мнемокода операции символом ":" ("двоеточие"). На этапе ассемблирования любой метке
соответствует некоторое значение программного счетчика, таким образом, метка может
расcматриваться как символический адрес, на который могут ссылаться другие команды
программы. Кодирование операндов в командах осуществляется следующим образом:
• если операнд является регистром, то в поле операндов он кодируется номером
регистра(0 или 1);
• если операндом является содержимое ячейки памяти, то в поле операндов
записывается символический или абсолютный шестнадцатеричный адрес
соответствующей ячейки памяти;
• если операнд является адресом ячейки памяти, то в поле операндов указывается
либо символический, либо абсолютный шестнадцатеричный адрес памяти.
Список команд:

INP A - ввод слова из канала ввода и запись его по адресу A.
OUT A - вывод содержимого ячейки памяти с адресом A в канал вывода.
MOVR R,A - загрузка регистра R содержимым ячейки памяти с адресом A.
MOVM R,A - запись содержимого регистра R в ячейку памяти с адресом A.
ARM R,A - сложить содержимое регистра R с содержимым ячейки памяти с
адресом A.
SRM R,A - из содержимого регистра R вычесть содержимое ячейки памяти с
адресом A.
MRM R,A - перемножить содержимое регистра R и ячейки памяти с адресом
A.
DRM R,A - поделить содержимое регистра R на содержимое ячейки памяти
с адресом A.
ARR R1,R2 - сложить содержимое регистров R1 и R2.
SRR R1,R2 - из содержимого R1 вычесть содержимое R2.
MRR R1,R2 - содержимое регистра R1 умножить на содержимое регистра
R2.
DRR R1,R2 - содержимое регистра R1 поделить на содержимое регистра R2.
AMM A1,A2 - сложить содержимое ячеек памяти с адресами A1 и A2.
SMM A1,A2 - из содержимого ячейки с адресом A1 вычесть содержимое
ячейки памяти с адресом A2.
MMM A1,A2 - перемножить содержимое ячеек памяти с адресами A1 и A2.
DMM A1,A2 - содержимое ячейки памяти с адресом A1 поделить на
содержимое ячейки памяти с адресом A2.
JMP A - безусловный переход по адресу A.
JV A - переход по переполнению по адресу A.
JP A - переход по положительному результату по адресу A.
JPV A - переход по переполнению или положительному результату по
адресу A.
JZ A - переход по нулевому результату.
JZV A - переход по неотрицательному и неположительному результату.
JZP A - переход по положительному или нулевому результату.
JZPV A - переход по неотрицательному результату.
JN A - переход по отрицательному результату.
JNV A - переход по отрицательному результату или переполнению.
JNP A - переход по отрицательному или нулевому результату.
JNPV A - переход по ненулевому результату.
JNZ A - переход по отрицательному или нулевому результату.
JNZV A - переход по неположительному результату.
JNZP A - переход по непереполнению.
LOOP A - организация цикла со счетчиком в регистре 0.
STOP - останов.

Директива определения ячейки памяти присваивает ячейке памяти символический
адрес и обеспечивает занесение в эту ячейку значения, указанного в качестве параметра
директивы. Формат директивы следующий:
[метка:] .DW параметр
Здесь параметр - шестнадцатеричное число не более чем из трех значащих цифр.
Если число начинается с шестнадцатеричных цифр A, B,C, D, E или F, то перед первой
значащей цифрой числа должен стоять 0.
Директива резервирования ячейки памяти только присваивает ячейке памяти
символический адрес. Формат директивы следующий:
[метка:] .DS
Цикл реализуется так:

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как впихнуть формулу в оставшиеся 4 строки...

Что за "оставшиеся 4 строки"? У вас ограничено место под код?

да, ограничено, только 16 строк

У вас в формуле сложение, в ваших инструкциях есть сложение, вот его и используйте

Так то тут просто слагаемое нужно каждый раз на 1 больше делать. Но потом ещё нужно знак менять у каждого слагаемого, и вот тут я не знаю как это быстро и просто сделать. Либо тут вычитать/добавлять в зависимости от ещё одной переменной.

@tym32167, простите, не совсем понимаю как мне это поможет(

@CrazyElf, вот в этом и проблема, что непонятно как уместить

@SnowLeopard А вы попробуйте сначала довести до ума вариант без смены знака. А там видно будет.

А вообще у вас же тут есть умножение MRM. В общем, сделайте для начала вариант, который не умещается. А код который приведён на картинке менять нельзя? Может там можно тоже где-то сэкономить. И вообще приведите код текстом, а не картинкой.

А ну-ка, проверяйте... Писал на ходу, мог что-то и пропустить.
       MOVR 0, N   ; организация цикла
CYCL:  MOVR 1, K   ; множитель (-1)^i
       MRM  1, A   ; умножение на значение a+i
       SMM  A, M   ; увеличение a (значение a+i для следующей итерации) 
       MMM  K, M   ; смена знака (-1)^i
       AMR  S, 1   ; вычисление окончательной суммы
       LOOP CYCL   ; цикл N раз
       OUT  S      ; вывод суммы
       STOP
N: .DW  5   ; исходные 
A: .DW  2   ;    значения
M: .DW -1   ; константа
K: .DW  1   ; текущее (-1)^i
S: .DW  0   ; сумма

На каждой итерации после просчета просто увеличиваем A на 1.

Тяжко с непривычки читать ассемблерные сокращения. Там нельзя комментарии сделать на каждой строчке - что там происходит? )  И в какой ячейке памяти что лежит.

Забавная экономия одной ячейки через вычитание -1 вместо добавления 1, чтобы этот же -1 использовать для смены знака. )

@CrazyElf Я ж говорю, писалось практически со скоростью битья по клавишам... Комментариев достаточно?

Я в общем-то и сам потихоньку разобрался, но всё-равно спасибо за комментарии, я думаю полезно будет )

@CrazyElf Главное, разобрался ли автор вопроса :)

@Harry, большое спасибо, получилось! Только кое-что поменял: во строке 1 на CYCL: JZ OU, а MOVR 1, K передвинул в цикл, где AMR  S, 1 поменял на ARM 1, S и MOVM 1, S

MOVR 0, N     *организация цикла
CYCL:  JZ OU
MOVR 1, K      *множитель (-1)^i
MRM  1, A      *умножение на значение a+i
SMM  A, M     *увеличение a (значение a+i для следующей итерации)
MMM  K, M    *смена знака (-1)^i
ARM  1, S        *вычисление окончательной суммы
MOVM 1, S     *запись суммы в S
LOOP CYCL     *цикл N раз
OU: OUT  S     *вывод суммы
STOP
N: .DW  5   *исходные
A: .DW  2    *значения
M: .DW -1  *константа
K: .DW  1    *текущее (-1)^i
S: .DW  0    *сумма

Не очень понимаю, зачем вам вообще переход JZ. Или N у вас может иметь нулевое значение? но тогда проверка должна быть до цикла...
